# How to design a failsafe upload mechanism?

Tags: python

At my Python application, I do a lot of data processing which in the end generates a lot of small files, sometimes more than 20.000 per job.
Later in my processing-flow, I upload all these files to an S3 storage. The problem is that sometimes for some reason not all files reach the S3 storage, which I don't understand as I explicitly check if the file is there:

```
    count_lock = threading.Lock()
    obj_count = 0

    def __upload(object_path_pair):
        global obj_count
        sleep_time = 5
        num_retries = 10
        for x in range(0, num_retries):
            try:
                libera_resource.upload_file(*object_path_pair)
                sleep(random.uniform(1, 5))
                with count_lock:
                    libera_resource_status = libera_resource.Object(object_path_pair[1]).get()['ResponseMetadata'].get('HTTPStatusCode')
                    if libera_resource_status == 200 and obj_count > 0:
                        print(f'Item: {file_name} - HLS segment {obj_count} / {len(segment_upload_list)} uploaded successfully.')
                    elif libera_resource_status != 200:
                        print(f'Item: {file_name} - HLS segment {obj_count} / {len(segment_upload_list)} uploaded failed, will be tried again.')
                    obj_count += 1
                    upload_error = None
            except Exception as upload_error:
                pass
            if upload_error or libera_resource_status != 200:
                sleep(sleep_time)  # wait before trying to fetch the data again
                sleep_time *= 2
            else:
                break

    def upload_segments(segment_upload_list):
        global obj_count
        obj_count = 0
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
            executor.map(__upload, segment_upload_list)

    upload_segments(segment_upload_list)
```

Here, libera_ressource basically is boto3.resource. Can somebody tell where and why I might sometimes miss a file?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code probably isn't doing what you expect when an exception is encountered:

```
try:
    # (stuff)
    upload_error = None
except Exception as upload_error:
    pass
if upload_error or libera_resource_status != 200:
    # more stuff
```

If an exception is encountered, it's assigned into `upload_error` for the `except` clause, but `upload_error` is then **deleted on exit from the `except` clause**. See [PEP 3110](https://peps.python.org/pep-3110/#semantic-changes) and [this Reddit discussion](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/7e98f0/scope_of_except_exception_as_e/).

So if you get an exception, the subsequent `if` statement throws (because `uploadError` is now unassigned) and you've crashed out of your `__upload` function without retrying.

This won't cause the other threads in your pool to fail, so it's easy to miss if you're not [checking for it](https://superfastpython.com/threadpoolexecutor-exception-handling/).

Comment: Makes a lot of sense, but It's still not clear to me how to keep it then. Can I simply declare the error as a new variable and that's it? like: '''except Exception as upload_error:
                        potential_error = upload_error
                        pass'''

Comment: You could do something like `except Exception: upload_error = True` (since really you're just using `upload_error` as a boolean for use in a conditional)